Headers on alternating pages
Compiling this code doesn't put headers
on alternating pages for the entire paper.
It seems the problem is from the following: notice that in \begin{proof} environment we have
\par
\ \\
\noindent\rule{0.84in}{0.4pt} \par
\medskip
\indent\indent {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt} \selectfont DOI: 10.35834/YYYY/VVNNPPP \par}
\indent\indent {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt} \selectfont MSC2020: 54A40 \par}
\indent\indent {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt} \selectfont Key words and phrases: $L$-topology, scott topology, lattice, atom, dual atom \par}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\vfil\eject
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\hfill HYPERGEOMETRIC TEMPLATE}
\fancyhead[CE]{K.~DILCHER\hfill}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

If this was removed then the headers will reappear (the above coding is crucially needed in the proof environment)
What is the solution for this problem? (This is our only concern)
Source of the code is here: http://cs.ucmo.edu/~mjms/template.html
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.5in}
\setlength{\voffset}{-.25in}
%\hyphenation{Fibonacci}
%\sloppy
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,amssymb,dsfont}

\textwidth=4.5in
\textheight=7.0in

\newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}
\newcommand{\Q}{{\mathbb Q}}
\newcommand{\C}{{\mathbb C}}
\newcommand{\N}{{\mathbb N}}
\newcommand{\minus}{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}
%\textendash

\theoremstyle{plain}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[thm]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}[thm]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[thm]{Definition}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\helv}{
  \fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{m}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\medskip \thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\medskip MISSOURI J.~OF MATH.~SCI., SPRING 2021}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\medskip MISSOURI J.~OF MATH.~SCI., VOL.~33, NO.~1}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\title[Hypergeometric TEMPLATE]{Hypergeometric TEMPLATE}
\author{Karl Dilcher}
\address{Department of Mathematics and Statistics\\
                Dalhousie University\\
                Halifax, Nova Scotia\\
                B3H 3J5, Canada}
\email{dilcher@mathstat.dal.ca}

\begin{abstract}
We provide a new proof of the following theorem: if $(d,p) \in \N^* \times \R_+^*$ and $f:\R^d \longrightarrow \R$ is a $\left(\mathcal{B}\left(\R^d\right),\mathcal{B}\left(\R\right)\right)$-measurable function such that $\int_{\R^d}|f(x)|^p\, \mathrm{d}x<+\infty,$ then $\lim_{h \to 0}\int_{\R^d}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^p\, \mathrm{d}x=0.$
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

The purpose of this short note is to present a new elementary proof of the following classical theorem from real analysis and avoiding the usual density arguments (see \cite{bib1, bib2, bib3} for more details).
\begin{theorem}
\label{theorem}
If $(d,p) \in \N^* \times \R_+^*$ and $f:\R^d \longrightarrow \R$ is a $\left(\mathcal{B}\left(\R^d\right),\mathcal{B}\left(\R\right)\right)$-measurable function such that $\int_{\R^d}|f(x)|^p \, \mathrm{d}x<+\infty,$ then $$\lim_{h \to 0}\int_{\R^d}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^p\, \mathrm{d}x=0.$$
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Let $\left(\R^d,\Vert \cdot \Vert\right)$ be the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space and $\left(h_k\right)_{k \in \N}$ be a sequence in $\R^d$ such that $\lim_{q \to +\infty}\left\Vert h_q \right\Vert=0$ and $$\forall k \in \N,\left\Vert h_k\right\Vert \leq 1.$$

\sloppy For all $q \in \N^*,$ let $X_q:=\left\{x \in \R^d,\Vert x\Vert \leq q\right\}$, $\mathcal{F}_q:=\left\{U \in \mathcal{B}\left(\R^d\right),\lim_{k \to +\infty}\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_U\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_U(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x=0\right\},$ and
\begin{align*}
f_q: \R^d &\longrightarrow \R \\
x & \longmapsto f_q\left(x\right)
\begin{aligned}[t]
&=\left(\min \left(2^{-q}\left\lfloor2^q\max\left(f\left(x\right),0\right)\right\rfloor,q\right)\right.\\
& \phantom{\leq}\ \left.-\min\left(2^{-q}\left\lfloor2^q\max\left(-f\left(x\right),0\right)\right\rfloor,q\right)\right)\mathds{1}_{X_q}\left(x\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
First, we will prove that for every $q \in \N^*,\mathcal{F}_q$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\R^d.$

We fix $q \in \N^*.$

We note that $\R^d \in \mathcal{F}_q.$
\par
\ \\
\noindent\rule{0.84in}{0.4pt} \par
\medskip
\indent\indent {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt} \selectfont DOI: 10.35834/YYYY/VVNNPPP \par}
\indent\indent {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt} \selectfont MSC2020: 54A40 \par}
\indent\indent {\fontsize{8pt}{9pt} \selectfont Key words and phrases: $L$-topology, scott topology, lattice, atom, dual atom \par}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\vfil\eject
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CO]{\hfill HYPERGEOMETRIC TEMPLATE}
\fancyhead[CE]{K.~DILCHER\hfill}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\noindent Let $U \in \mathcal{F}_q$ and $V \in \mathcal{F}_q$ such that $U \subset V.$

Since for every $k \in \N,$

\begin{align*}
\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{V \setminus U}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{V\setminus U}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x &\leq 2^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{V}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{V}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +2^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{U}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_U(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}
it follows that $V \setminus U \in \mathcal{F}_q.$

Let $\left(V_k\right)_{k \in \N}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{F}_q$ such that $$\forall k \in \N,V_{k} \subset V_{k+1}.$$
We have for all $(r,k) \in \N^2,$
\begin{align*}
&\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\begin{aligned}[t]
&\leq 3^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{V_r}\left(x+h_k\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{V_r}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{V_r}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x+3^p \int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{V_r}\left(x\right)-\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\leq 3^p\int_{\R^d}\mathds{1}_{X_q}\left(x-h_k\right)\left|\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}\left(x\right)-\mathds{1}_{V_r}\left(x\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{V_r}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{V_r}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p \int_{X_{q+1}}\left|\mathds{1}_{V_r}\left(x\right)-\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\leq 2\int_{X_{q+1}}\left|3\left(\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}\left(x\right)-\mathds{1}_{V_r}\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{V_r}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{V_r}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}


Letting $k \to +\infty$ we obtain that for every $r \in \N,$


\begin{align*}
&\limsup_{k \to +\infty} \int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq 2\int_{X_{q+1}}\left|3\left(\mathds{1}_{\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n}(x)-\mathds{1}_{V_r}(x)\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
Taking $r \to +\infty$ and applying the dominated convergence theorem, we deduce that $\bigcup_{n \in \N}V_n \in \mathcal{F}_q.$

Let $W \in \mathcal{F}_q$ and $G \in \mathcal{F}_q.$

Noticing that for all $k \in \N,$
\begin{align*}
&\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{W\cap G}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{W \cap G}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq 2^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{W}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_W(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x+2^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{G}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_G(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}
We get that $W \cap G \in \mathcal{F}_q.$

Therefore for every $q \in \N^*,\mathcal{F}_q$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\R^d.$

Next, we check that $$\forall q \in \N^*,\mathcal{B}\left(\R^d\right)\subset \mathcal{F}_q.$$

Let $q \in \N^*$ and $Y$ be a non-empty closed set in $\R^d.$

For all $k \in \N,$ let
\begin{align*}
\phi_k: \R^d &\longrightarrow \R \\ x & \longmapsto \phi_k(x)=\frac{1}{\left(1+\inf_{y \in Y}\Vert x-y\Vert\right)^k}
\end{align*}
For every $k \in \N,\phi_k$ is a continuous function on $\R^d$ and $\left|\phi_k\right| \leq 1.$

For all $\left(r,k\right) \in \N^2,$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{Y}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{Y}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x &\leq 3^p\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{Y}\left(x+h_k\right)-\phi_r\left(x+h_k\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p\int_{X_q}\left|\phi_r\left(x+h_k\right)-\phi_r(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p \int_{X_q}\left|\phi_r\left(x\right)-\mathds{1}_{Y}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\leq 3^p\int_{\R^d}\mathds{1}_{X_q}\left(x-h_k\right)\left|\mathds{1}_{Y}\left(x\right)-\phi_r\left(x\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p\int_{X_q}\left|\phi_r\left(x+h_k\right)-\phi_r(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
& \phantom{\leq}\ +3^p \int_{X_{q+1}}\left|\phi_r\left(x\right)-\mathds{1}_{Y}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\leq 2\int_{X_{q+1}}\left|3\left(\phi_r\left(x\right)-\mathds{1}_{Y}\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
& \phantom{\leq}\ +3^p\int_{X_q}\left|\phi_r\left(x+h_k\right)-\phi_r(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}\\
Letting $k \to \infty$ and using the dominated convergence theorem, we find that for every $r \in \N,$\\
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{k \to +\infty}\int_{X_q}\left|\mathds{1}_{Y}\left(x+h_k\right)-\mathds{1}_{Y}(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x \leq 2\int_{X_{q+1}}\left|3\left(\phi_r\left(x\right)-\mathds{1}_{Y}\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
Since $\lim_{r \to +\infty}\phi_r=\mathds{1}_Y,$ it follows from the dominated convergence theorem that $\lim_{r \to +\infty}\int_{X_{q+1}}\left|3\left(\phi_r(x)-\mathds{1}_Y(x)\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x=0.$

Hence $$\forall q \in \N^*,\mathcal{B}\left(\R^d\right)\subset \mathcal{F}_q.$$
For all $\left(r,k\right) \in \left(\N^*\right)^2,$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\R^d}\left|f\left(x+h_k\right)-f(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x &\leq 3^p\int_{\R^d}\left|f\left(x+h_k\right)-f_r\left(x+h_k\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p\int_{\R^d}\left|f_r\left(x+h_k\right)-f_r(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{\leq}\ +3^p \int_{\R^d}\left|f_r\left(x\right)-f(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\leq 2\int_{\R^d}\left|3\left(f_r\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x\\
& \phantom{\leq}\ +3^p\int_{X_{r+1}}\left|f_r\left(x+h_k\right)-f_r(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
Lastly, noticing that $\left(f_k\right)_{k \in \N^*}$ is a sequence of simple functions such that $\lim_{r \to +\infty}f_r=f$ and $$\forall k \in \N^*,\left|f_k-f\right|^p \leq |f|^p,$$ we obtain that $$\forall r \in \N^*,\limsup_{k \to +\infty}\int_{\R^d}\left|f\left(x+h_k\right)-f(x)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x \leq 2\int_{\R^d}\left|3\left(f_r(x)-f(x)\right)\right|^p\, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Applying the dominated convergence theorem, we conclude the proof.
\end{proof}
\begin{remark}
Our approach gives a new proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma (we refer to \cite{bib3} for a general statement and a proof using Theorem \ref{theorem}).
\end{remark}
\begin{remark}
\sloppy Applying the procedure used in proving Theorem \ref{theorem} we can show that if $p \in \R_+^*,\left(E,d\right)$ is a metric space, $\left(E,\mathcal{B}\left(E\right),\mu\right)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $f:E\longrightarrow \R$ is a $\left(\mathcal{B}\left(E\right),\mathcal{B}\left(\R\right)\right)$-measurable function, and $\left(g_k,g\right)_{k \in \N}$ is a sequence in $\left(E^2\right)^E$ such that for any $\left(k,\epsilon\right) \in \N \times \R_+^*$ and all $V \in \mathcal{B}\left(E\right),\left(g_k,g\right)$ is a $\left(\mathcal{B}\left(E\right),\mathcal{B}\left(E^2\right)\right)$-measurable function, $\mu\left(g_k^{-1}\left(V\right)\right)=\mu\left(g_0^{-1}\left(V\right)\right),\int_{E}\left|f\left(g_0\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)<+\infty,$ and $\lim_{q \to +\infty}\mu\left(\left\{x \in E,d\left(g_q\left(x\right),g\left(x\right)\right)>\epsilon\right\}\right)=0,$ then $\int_{E}\left|f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)<+\infty$ and $\lim_{q \to +\infty}\int_{E}\left|f\left(g_q\left(x\right)\right)-f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=0$ by the following sequence of arguments:
\begin{enumerate}
\item There exists a sequence $\left(E_q\right)_{q \in \N}$ in $\mathcal{B}\left(E\right)$ such that for all $k \in \N,E_k \subset E_{k+1},\mu\left(E_k\right)<+\infty,$ and $E=\bigcup_{r \in \N}E_r.$
\item For every $q \in \N,$
\begin{align*}
f_q: E &\longrightarrow \R \\
x & \longmapsto f_q(x)
\begin{aligned}[t]
&=\left(\min \left(2^{-q}\left\lfloor2^q\max\left(f\left(x\right),0\right)\right\rfloor,q\right)\right.\\
& \phantom{=}\ \left.-\min\left(2^{-q}\left\lfloor2^q\max\left(-f\left(x\right),0\right)\right\rfloor,q\right)\right)\mathds{1}_{E_q}\left(x\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
is a simple function and $\lim_{r \to +\infty}f_r=f.$
\item For all $q \in \N,$ $\left\{U \in \mathcal{B}\left(E\right),\lim_{r \to +\infty}\int_{E_q}\left|\mathds{1}_U\left(g_r\left(x\right)\right)\right.\right.$ $\left.\vphantom{\left\{U \in \mathcal{B}\left(E\right),\lim_{r \to +\infty}\int_{E_q}\left|\mathds{1}_U\left(g_r\left(x\right)\right)\right.\right.}\left.-\mathds{1}_{U}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d} \mu(x) =0\right\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and $\left\{U \in \mathcal{B}\left(E\right),\mu\left(g_0^{-1}\left(U\right) \cap E_q\right)=\mu\left(g^{-1}\left(U\right)\cap E_q\right)\right\}$ is a $\lambda$-system on $E.$
\item If $Y$ is a non-empty closed set of $E,$ then for every $q \in \N$, $\mu\left(g_0^{-1}\left(Y\right) \cap E_q\right)=\mu\left(g^{-1}\left(Y\right)\cap E_q\right)$ and $\lim_{r \to +\infty}\int_{E_q}\left|\mathds{1}_Y\left(g_r\left(x\right)\right)-\mathds{1}_Y\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=0.$
\item $\int_E\left|f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)<+\infty$ and for all $\left(r,q\right) \in \N^2,$
\begin{align*}
&\int_E\left|f\left(g_r\left(x\right)\right)-f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu\left(x\right) \\
&\leq 2\int_E\left|3\left(f_q\left(g_0\left(x\right)\right)-f\left(g_0\left(x\right)\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu\left(x\right)\\
& \phantom{=}\ +3^p\int_{E_q}\left|f_q\left(g_r\left(x\right)\right)-f_q\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x).
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{remark}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{bib1} G. B. Folland, Real analysis: modern techniques and their applications, 2nd ed., Wiley, New York, 1999.

\bibitem{bib2} W. Rudin, Real and complex analysis, 3rd ed., McGraw-Hill, New York, 1987.

\bibitem{bib3} R. L. Wheeden and A. Zygmund, Measure and integral: an introduction to real analysis, 2nd ed., CRC Press, Boca Raton, FL, 2015.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document} 


Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at this guide for how to prune your code for this purpose.

Well it is RELEVANT, the problem lies in the coding (headers not showing on the last 2 pages) we prune the code, then this WONT SHOW THE REAL PROBLEM (this one: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225 is for a thesis, ours is barely 4-5 pages article, therefore there is no COMPARISON)

Well, prune and prune again until you find the culprit. Does the bibliography play a vital role in this issue? Do you really need $$ for display math? Is \vfil\eject really proper LaTeX? In other words: There are a lot of opportunities, to narrow it down.

You don't specify any headers. You only specify footers with \fancyfoot.

Kindly note this is not our code. Source of the code is here: http://cs.ucmo.edu/~mjms/template.html the headers appears on all pages alternating if the code from website is compiled, we didn't change the code, we only replaced the text but while we compile the headers on page 4-5 do not appear

There is \fancyhead{} also \fancyfoot{} we are not sure if this the reason. Also pruning the code WILL NOT SHOW THE PROBLEM you need at least 4-5 pages to see (headers WILL appear for 1-3 pages alternating) the issue

this is quite horrible code. And you do not need all this stuff to demonstrate the problem. A short text + \newpage is enough to produce 5 pages.

We "experimented" and find the source of the problem see edited text

you could easily reduce your example, if you've isolated the problem. you're right that the linked code is also horrible. try  configuring the headers outside the proof environment so they aren't local to that group. e.g. in a shipout hook or something. since you don't define the headers anywhere else, it's hard to see how removing those definitions could have the effect you say. (though the class may be adding headers you don't define.)
